# iOS touch event bug on ios 14.4

Tags: ios, touch-event

only on iPhone 12 Pro Max iOS 14.4
When I click the back button on navigationBar
the touch event pass to the bottom collectionView cell
Any idea can fix this question?

Here is the hitTest on UIWindow's log when click back button

```java
2021-06-30 15:55:27.724531+0800 FOURTRY[36793:4319245] hit test view ---- <UIButton: 0x7fee71054bb0; frame = (0 44; 44 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CAGradientLayer: 0x600003fb9400>>
2021-06-30 15:55:27.724987+0800 FOURTRY[36793:4319245] hit test view ---- <UIButton: 0x7fee71054bb0; frame = (0 44; 44 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CAGradientLayer: 0x600003fb9400>>
2021-06-30 15:55:27.725386+0800 FOURTRY[36793:4319245] hit test view ---- <UIView: 0x7fee6f72d140; frame = (0 0; 213.5 343.051); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000306f4e0>; layer = <CAGradientLayer: 0x600003fbd540>>
2021-06-30 15:55:27.725702+0800 FOURTRY[36793:4319245] hit test view ---- <UIView: 0x7fee6f72d140; frame = (0 0; 213.5 343.051); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000306f4e0>; layer = <CAGradientLayer: 0x600003fbd540>>
```

UIView: 0x7fee6f72d140 is the collectionView cell, Why happen this?

[image]

[image]